# Show that if $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a decreasing series of events, then its limit is $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$

Tags: probability

Let $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a decreasing series of events.

Show that $$\lim_nA_n = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$$

For this to be true, we need to show that

$$\lim_n \inf A_n = \lim_n \sup A_n = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$$

---

Reminder

$$\lim_n \inf A_n = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{m=n}^\infty A_m \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_n \sup A_n = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{m=n}^\infty A_m$$

---

Since $A_n$ is a decreasing series of events, we know that $A_{n+1} \subset A_n$. Thus:

$$\bigcup_{m=n}^\infty A_m = A_n$$

So $$\lim_n \sup A_n = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$$

By definition

$$\lim_n \inf A_n \subset \lim_n \sup A_n$$

So showing that

$$\lim_n \inf A_n = \lim_n \sup A_n = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$$

boils down to showing that

$$\lim_n \sup A_n \subset \lim_n \inf A_n$$

or, in other words

$$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n \subset \lim_n \inf A_n$$

---

That's where I'm stuck... :(

Comment: And now based on your arguments, in the last line you mean actually the opposite: $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\subseteq \liminf A_n$ or not?

Comment: @JimmyR. & toogy : It is standard to use $\cap$ in things like $A\cap B$ and $A_1\cap\cdots\cap A_n$ and $\displaystyle\bigcap$ in things like $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$.  I changed it. $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHardy, didn't know about it! *Learning a new $\LaTeX$ mathematical symbol every day*

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, of course, I have it like this in my answer, but was lazy to fix it in the OP :). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $n\in \mathbb N$ $$\bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty}A_m \subseteq \bigcap_{m=n}^{\infty}A_m \implies \bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty}A_m \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{m=n}^{\infty}A_m=\liminf_n A_n$$

Answer (score 1):

If $x \in \lim_n \sup A_n$ then $x$ is in infinitely many of the $A_n$. Suppose that $x \in A_{n_1}, A_{n_2}, \ldots $. Since the $A_n$ are decreasing, from $x \in A_m$ we can conclude that $x \in A_1, \ldots, A_{m-1}$. Since the sequence $n_1, n_2, \ldots $ tends to infinity, it follows that $x$ is in fact in every $A_n$. Hence $\lim_n \sup A_n \subseteq \bigcap_n A_n$, as required.